# Array Formatting PHP

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

This is my code in php.

```
$approveddata=  "SELECT DATE AS DATE, company_id, count As Approved
                            FROM tbl_summary_order
                            WHERE DATE >= DATE( NOW( ) ) - INTERVAL 7 
                            DAY AND STATUS =4
                            GROUP BY company_id, DATE( DATE ) 
                                ORDER BY DATE ASC "

while ($_row = $rsqueryapproveddata->read()) {

    $list1[$_row['DATE']][$_row['company_id']] = $_row['Approved'];
}
```

I am getting the output as

```
 "data": {
    "2018-01-30": { "1": "10",   "2": "5" },
    "2018-01-31": {     "1": "10" }
}
```

But I need a format 'to add the date inside every inner array.

Some thing like the below format

```
data: [{ date: '2018-01-30', 1: 10, 2: 5, }, { date: '2018-01-31', 1: 10 }
```

Comment: Some thing like the below format `data: [{ date: '2018-01-30', 1: 10, 2: 5, }, { date: '2018-01-31', 1: 10 }

Comment: Sahan, you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48601432/edit) your post, instead of add comments to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize `$list1` with an associative array that contains the current date value, and then when the loop is finished use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to get the result as a numeric array:

```
while ($_row = $rsqueryapproveddata->read()) {

    if ( !isset( $list1[ $_row['DATE'] ] ) {
        $list1[ $_row['DATE'] ] = [ 'date' => $_row['DATE'] ]
    }

    $list1[ $_row['DATE'] ] [ $_row['company_id'] ] = $_row['Approved'];  

}

$result = array_values($list1);
```